# PyAudio record audio while button is pressed down

Tags: python, button, kivy, pyaudio

I'm try to record audio input while a button is pressed in Kivy using PyAudio. I have tried loads of different ways and nothing seems to work, so I was wondering if anyone could give me some help?! The issue is that the Python file doesn't seem to detect when the Kivy button is released (when its state is changed from 'down' to 'normal').

Here's the Python code:

```
    def on_press(self):
        self.frames = []
        self.audio_filename = "item_audio.wav"
        chunk = 2048  # data is broken into chunks (buffers) of audio. In this case, each chunk contains 1024 frames (a frame is the total number of samples which occur at the same moment in time. If the audio is mono, then each frame contains 1 sample. If the audio is stereo, then each frame contains 2 samples (one from each channnel)
        Format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 'paInt16' is the sampling format. In this case, each sample contains 16 bits (2 bytes).
        channels = 2  # stero format. This means there are 2 samples in each frame.
        # As there are 2 bytes in each sample and 2 samples in each frame, there are 4 bytes in each frame. Therefore, there are 4096 bytes in each chunk (1024 frames*4 bytes).
        sample_rate = 44100  # Sampling rate (number of frames per second). In this case, 44100 frames per second
        self.record = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # initialise PyAudio object
        self.stream = self.record.open(format=Format,
                                       channels=channels,
                                       rate=sample_rate,
                                       input=True,
                                       output=True,
                                       frames_per_buffer=chunk)
        self.stream.start_stream()
        while self.ids.mic.state == "down":
            for i in range(0, int((sample_rate) / chunk)):  # (sample_rate * record_seconds) is the total number of frames recorded. As the for loop iterates through each chunk of frames and appends each chunk to the list 'frames', the total number of frames must be divided by the chunk size 'chunk'.
                self.data = self.stream.read(chunk)
                self.frames.append(self.data)
        self.stream.stop_stream()  # stops the stream (recording)
        self.stream.close()
        self.record.terminate()
        wf = wave.open(self.audio_filename, "wb")
        # set the channels
        wf.setnchannels(2)
        # set the sample format
        wf.setsampwidth(self.record.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        # set the sample rate
        wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
        # write the frames as bytes
        wf.writeframes(b"".join(self.frames))
        # close the file
        wf.close()

        # with speech.Microphone() as source:
        # recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        # while Boolean == True:
        # data = recognizer.record(source)
        # try:
        # text = recognizer.recognize_google(data, language="en-GB")
        # print(text)
        # except:
        # pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = Builder.load_file("layout.kv")  # loads the kv file
        return layout
```

And the .kv code:

```
<IdentifyItem>
    name: "identify_item"

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (6/250, 11/250, 26/250, 1) #each rgba colour code must be divided by 250 to convert to kivy colour code
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


    Image:
        id: mic_image
        source: "Mic_Static.png"
        size_hint: (0.6,0.6)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y": 0.2}

    Button:
        id: mic
        background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "y":0.09}
        size_hint: (0.2,0.19)
        on_press:
            root.on_press()
```

Comment: So this is basically the problem that kivy is not detecting button releases? Try debugging that first and then look at the audio problem.

Comment: Would you be able to help me debug that? That's the issue I've been struggling with.

Comment: Just do some test `print()`s. Print `'button pressed'` when your code realizes the button is pressed and `'button released'` when it is released

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I’ve already tried that. It seems that because the function is called when the button is pressed down, it doesn’t respond to changes in the buttons state.... Any ideas?

Comment: I mean there is a button release event for buttons. Maybe start looking into those and just thread the recording?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by ‘thread the recording’?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html